# Highchart spline Cut Off when reach to maximum scale value. How can it fixed?. I have attached may sample code on body

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm making use if the `highcharts` plugin to make a chart. But I'm running into some problems.
My Highchart spline is cut off when reach to maximum scale value. How is this possible and how can it be fixed?

I have created a sample demo for this chart and also attached the screenshot to point of the cutoff spline.
Here is my demo code:

```js
let chartdata = [];
let A = [95, 95, 95];
let B = [50, 100, 100];

var colorBand = [{
    color: "red",
    to: 0,
    from: 20
  },
  {
    color: "green",
    to: 21,
    from: 40
  },
  {
    color: "blue",
    to: 41,
    from: 60
  },
  {
    color: "orange",
    to: 61,
    from: 90
  },
  {
    color: "yellow",
    to: 91,
    from: 100
  },
];


chartdata.push({
  name: 'A',
  type: 'column',
  date: 'A',
  data: A,
  color: 'red',
});

chartdata.push({
  name: 'B',
  type: 'spline',
  date: 'B',
  data: B,
  color: 'blue'
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    height: 205,
    width: 200,
    background: '#F2F2F2'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  legend: {
    align: "center",
    layout: "horizontal",
    verticalAlign: "bottom",
    symbolHeight: 10,
    symbolWidth: 10,
    symbolRadius: 0,
    itemStyle: {
      fontSize: "13px",
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontFamily: '"Arial", sans-serif'
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    labels: {
      style: {
        fontSize: "11px",
        fontFamily: '"Arial", sans-serif',
        color: "#000"
      }
    },
    gridLineColor: "transparent",
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
    lineColor: "#9A9A9A",
    zIndex: 9999999,
    minorTickLength: 0,
    tickLength: 0,
    style: {
      fontSize: "11px",
      fontWeight: "bold",
      fontFamily: '"Arial", sans-serif',
      color: "#000"
    }
  },

  yAxis: [{
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      labels: {
        style: {
          fontSize: "12px",
          color: "#000",
          fontFamily: '"Arial", sans-serif'
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      min: 0,
      plotBands: colorBand,
      width: 20,
      max: 100,
      tickInterval: 20
    },
    {
      linkedTo: 0,
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      lineColor: "transparent",
      title: {
        text: ""
      },
      labels: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  ],
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        inactive: {
          opacity: 1
        }
      },
      pointPadding: 0.1,
      groupPadding: 0,
      lineWidth: 5,
      pointWidth: 25,
      enableMouseTracking: false,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
      threshold: 0, // let zero values have some height
      marker: {
        enabled: false,
        states: {
          hover: {
            //radius: 1
          }
        }
      },
      minPointLength: 10,
      events: {
        legendItemClick: function() {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: chartdata
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Here I pointed out the cutline

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRrBN.png)

Comment: Where would you want B spline to be ?

Comment: position will be as it is but it should not cut off, few portion of top part of spline actually cut off . If the cut off part will overflow then also fine and If we can make it bit inside then also fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cut line comes from the fact that you have a 5px lineWidth in your config. So in order to have the line not cut, you need to put it a 3px below where it is now, so that it has 2 pixels on top available (2pixels top + 2 pixels bottom + its pixel position = 5 pixels).

`let B = [97,97,97];`

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8w5roqpt/

Note that you could also increase the max size of your graph (yAxis.max): https://jsfiddle.net/sk4n9gp0/

Comment: B array can be 100 each. Its dynamic. Even if i make linewidth 3 still problem remain the same. spline cut off.

Comment: The line is cutoff because 100 is the max and so if you put the middle of the line at 100, it won't even have 1px to expand, that's why I proposed 97. Yes, I will edit your jsfiddle --> done, answer updated

Comment: @Benjamain value is dynamic and it can 100 too. Apart from making it 97 is there any solution to overcome this issue?

Comment: The fact that the value is dynamic is not really a problem, because you can do something like Math.min(value, 97) so you keep the dynamism while not ever going above 97. That being said, there is another solution which is to increase the max yValue of your graph. I added another jsfiddle for that.

Comment: y-axis max value should not cross 100 Scale. Any other way you suggest?

Comment: I tried to play with spacing, margin and padding, but without success. Thing is, you want a line that is 3 or 5 pixels thick with the middle at 100 in a chart where the max is 100, so you will lack some place at some point.

Comment: I can't think of any other trick than the Math.min(value, 97) given your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `series.clip` as a false is a solution which you are looking for.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aph9tg78/

```
chartdata.push({
    clip: false,
  name: 'B',
  type: 'spline',
  date : 'B',
  data : B,
  color: 'blue'
});
```

Simplified demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/483obfrw/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.clip